# Where to find the seed for the wallets that were created inside BitBox by Shift Crypto

Tags: seed, hardware-wallet

I bought the Swiss hardware wallet BitBox2 in order to have a safe storage for my private keys and now I am disappointed because under `Manage device > Show recovery words` there is only one seed for the whole BitBox. In order to have full access to my wallets (independently of the BitBox) I had the notion that the BitBox just stores the various private keys for me, but now I feel like in a vendor lock-in. Probably it is by design that I cannot access the private keys of every wallet - if the information does not surface, it cannot be stolen. Can someone confirm my thoughts?

Comment: The BitBox02 doesn't store your private keys, it derives them from the mnemonic (+ passphrase). You can recover all your private keys, just with the mnemonic. There is no vendor lock-in here... What do you mean with "only one seed for the whole BitBox"?

Answer (score 0):

You can import your seed phase into another wallet and access your ERC20 token and technically BitBox Support only BTC, LTC, ETH & ERC20 So what private key are you looking for it's not like it supports XMR, DASH, ALGO, HBAR, ZCASH, etc. Then you should be looking for PKs